# Unix Shell - find number of columns from a very large file

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to find all the line/row numbers from a file, where number of columns in a row != 25 (the file is separated by `pipe (|)`. Means in ideal scenario there should be 25 columns in each row and I want to find the row numbers where is actually more (can be less) than 25.

I have tried to use the below command

```
cat filename|awk -F"|" 'NF != 25 {print NR}' > outputfile
```

The main concern is the source file is 400 GB and so the command is running for long more than 2 hours and not getting completed.

Is there any other way I can achieve the same thing but quickly.

Comment: It might be better to split the file in smaller files (400 files of 1GB) and run `awk` on each file.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask]. Your sample does NOT need to have 25 columns - 5 rows of 4-6 columns should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your original command (if you are looking for column numbers, not number of columns in which case see @EdMorton's answer BELOW :) except the useless use of `cat`.

```
$ time awk -F\| 'NF != 25 {print NR}' my_350_gb_file > /dev/null

real    0m13.685s
user    0m13.512s
sys     0m0.172s
```

If you are printing those line numbers on screen and there are plenty it might take a while.